# ODE45 in Matlab trouble with Diode Model

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to model the system that is shown in the picture below.  I have modeled before in ODE45 with Matlab but for some reason I keep getting a strange output with the following code.  I am not sure if it is because I put in the conditional of if( (Vin - Vd - Vc)/Ll >= 0 ) which helps prevent any current flowing in the wrong direction of the diode when it is reversed biased.

I tried to attach the picture but my rep isn't high enough, really guys?, so I have to describe it.

```
source -> Inductor(Ll) -> diode -> Capacitor -> ground
                               |->Inductor(Lline)->resistor(Rf) -> ground
```

Any help is appreciated!

```
function dy = ThreeLamp(t,y)

I1 = y(1);
I2 = y(2);
Vc = y(3);

Is = 1E-15;                                     % these are parameters for the diode
n = 1.05;
Vt = .025;

D = 24;                                        % this number is from 0 to 50
f = 100E3;                                     % this is the frequency of the input waveform
Ll = 5E-7;
Lline = 5.3E-6;
C = 10E-6;
Rf = 10;
Vin = (465/2)*(6/266)*square(2*pi*f*t,D);       % Input voltage waveform

if( Vin < 0 )                                   
   Vin = 0;                                     % get rid of negative half cycle
end

%%

Vd = n*Vt*log(I1/Is + 1)/log(10);               % This is the voltage across the diode

if( (Vin - Vd - Vc)/Ll >= 0 )                   % Is the diode conducting when forward biased?
    dy(1) = (Vin - Vd - Vc)/Ll;                 % Sounds good, what is the current?
else
    dy(1) = 0;                                  % force current to 0 when reversed biased
end
dy(2) = (Vc - I2*Rf)/Lline;                     % KCL for second loop
dy(3) = (I1 - I2)/C;                            % Voltage on cap

dy = dy';                                       % ODE45 likes output to be in columns

end

% [t, y] = ode45('ThreeLamp',[0 .001],[0 0 0 ]);
```

Comment: Why is the output "strange"? What do you expect?

Comment: I would try a stiff solver like `ode15s` or `ode23t`. Also do you have access to Simulink and Simscape? If so, there is a library of electrical components that may make modelling your system easier:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/simscape/simscapeblocklist.html

Comment: `ode15s` gives virtually the same result. Smaller tolerances don't seem to change much either.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the exact same issue trying to model a DCDC boost converter.  Like am304 says, a stiff solver may be the solution to this problem.  The discontinuity when the diode turns on/off is so stiff, it's very hard for a variable step solver to extract.  I found a fixed step solver worked well for my application.

**EDIT**

However, as horchler, brings up, there's no tolerance convergence or other numerical safety nets, so you must interpret your output very carefully.  Using a very small step size and being very judicious with the output, when the output has an expected shape, often will alleviate this issue.  Yet, horchler's warning must be heeded when attempting to solve a stiff system.  I have found that even if the fixed step method breaks down, the insight given into the solution can be worth the effort.

**END EDIT**

Also, you may want to check the direction of the current flow through the diode as well.  I found that I would get a large reverse bias current flowing through the diode, not possible!

I setup a circuit model [here](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/2fu3ap/ode45simtest/).  Here's a pic, is this the right topology?  HTH! [image: pic]

**EDIT**

Ok, now that I understand the circuit, I can maybe help with the derivative function, `ThreeLamp`.  If the diode is reverse biased, then the current through the inductor can not flow through the diode.  Therefore, the change in current at the point of the diode conducting/not conducting is large in order to cutoff the current through the diode at the same time as it cuts off through the inductor.  I think the issue likes around line 25 for the inductor current calculation.

Comment: Beware of using fixed step solvers for stiff systems. They happily integrate right over difficult stiff points in the system, thus introducing numerical error. It may seem like they're working because you don't get the warnings and errors that adaptive methods throw up, but you may be fooling yourself. If the system is truly stiff, one needs to use a really tiny fixed step size (problematic too) or get very lucky and discretize time in a way to best split up the discontinuities. Or one can use event detection techniques, but these generally work best with variable step size methods.

Comment: If you move the diode before the resistor and inductor then its the right model.  Yea, I will try the stiff solvers but horchler points out that it might not make a difference. . . I was expecting Vc to be a DC equivalent near the rms of the input waveform and have currents ~300mA going through the inductor and resistor.  There should be a transient where the cap gets an inrush but then the current through loop 1 should come down.

Comment: Did I write something wrong?  I find this very weird being a simple circuit that it is. . . hmmm